# Unserialise PHP string

Tags: php, arrays

I have a serialized string that gets returned from one of my functions:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:2:"id";s:24:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";s:11:"description";s:3:"Two";s:9:"users-idt";s:36:"x6543rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrd";}}
```

But when I used unserialize() on this it does not return an Array

```
<?php
 $arr = unserialize($string); //returns empty
```

Comment: The contents of your serialized data is invalid. Did you change some of the values?

Comment: Show the code used to create this string.

Comment: `s:36:"x6543rd"` that's not 36 characters long ditto `s:24:"xxid"`

Comment: Please see edit. The string is valid. But cant seem to get an array in return when running it through unserialize()

Comment: sigh, how can we help if you don't post the real data? and it is now fine: https://ideone.com/kE7kiZ

Comment: Works for me: https://3v4l.org/RBYN2

Comment: @LeanderIversen Does that really look like JSON to you?

Answer (score 1):

Your - *originally posted* - serialized string is invalid, see what counting the string len's gives, a proper result:

```
<?php
$original = 'a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:2:"id";s:24:"xxid";s:11:"description";s:3:"Two";s:9:"user-id";s:36:"x6543rd";}}';
                                     ||                                       ||            ||
                                     \/                                       \/            \/  
$edited   = 'a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:2:"id";s:4:"xxid";s:11:"description";s:3:"Two";s:7:"user-id";s:7:"x6543rd";}}';

$arr = unserialize($edited);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($arr);
echo '</pre>';
?>

//output
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "xxid"
    ["description"]=>
    string(3) "Two"
    ["user-id"]=>
    string(7) "x6543rd"
  }
}
```

Your - *edited* - string works fine, running it with the above code, output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(24) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ["description"]=>
    string(3) "Two"
    ["users-idt"]=>
    string(36) "x6543rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrd"
  }
}
```